# How to redirect with GET query in Zend 2?

Tags: redirect, get, zend-framework2, routes

I can redirect to matchable routes like `$this->redirect()->toRoute('controller', array('action' => 'something', 'foo' => 'bar'))`, but how can I append a get query? I'm using it for a filter for a table. The filter can either be submitted on the page (form get method), or linked from another page (need to add get query).

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
'course' => array(
    'type'    => 'Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route'    => '/course[/:action[/:id]]',
        'constraints' => array(
            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
            'id' => '\d+'
        ),
        'defaults' => array(
            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Home\Controller',
            'controller' => 'course',
            'action' => 'index',
            'id' => 0
        ),
    ),
    'may_terminate' => true,
    'child_routes' => array(
        'query' => array(
          'type' => 'Query',
          'options' => array(
            'route' => '?[:filterByDepartment]'
          ),
        ),  
    ),
),
```

make sure the route is met your need in the view :

```
echo $this->url('course/query', array('controller'=>'course', 'action'=>'index', 'id'=>0, 'filterByDepartment'=>'depA'));
```

if this is right, let's try the following in the controller action :

```
 $this->redirect()->toRoute('course/query', array('controller'=>'course', 'action'=>'index', 'id'=>0, 'filterByDepartment'=>'depA'));
```

Comment: `'course' => array(
 'type' => 'segment',
 'options' => array(
  'route' => '/course[/:action[/:id]]',
  'constraints' => array(
   'action' => '[a-zA-Z]*',
   'id' => '[0-9]*',
  ),
  'defaults' => array(
   'controller' => 'Home\Controller\Course',
   'action' => 'index',
   'id' => 0,
  ),
  'may_terminate' => true,
  'child_routes' => array(
   'query' => array(
    'type' => 'query',
    'options' => array(
     'route' => '?[:filterByDepartment]',
    ),
   ),
  ),
 ),
),` (I tried with uppercase Query too)

Comment: Still not routing. From the view, $this->url() is only producing the Controller part (I'm assuming it leaves out action because index is default, but the query doesn't come up either)